# Running a Inix command in a particular directory

Tags: java, unix, runtime.exec

I want to use Kava to unzip all files within a particular directory and subdirs.
If I open up terminal, I can use this:

```
find . -name '*.zip' -exec unzip {} \\
```

I want to run this at a certain point in my Java application and from a certain directory, and so I use this:

```
public void unzip() {
    try {
    Runtime unzipProcess = Runtime.getRuntime();
    unzipProcess.exec("find . -name '*.zip' -exec unzip {} \\");
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

This runs. If it works or not I do not know as I can't set the working directory.
I need to be able to do something like `unzipProcess.setWorkingDirectory("/Users/abc/")`.
But of course this method does not exist, I think I am doing something wrong.

How can I run this command in a particular directory?

Comment: capitalized `Kava` made me rotfl :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to *either*

- use the [three-argument version of `Runtime.exec()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.io.File%29) and pass the desired working directory in as a `File` argument *or*
- switch to [`ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) and call [`directory(File)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#directory%28java.io.File%29) before calling [`start()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#start%28%29).

Personally I strongly suggest using the `ProcessBuilder` as it has a much nicer API.

Generally I suggest reading [When Runtime.exec() won't](https://encrypted.google.com/search?rlz=1C1_____enAT460AT460&aq=f&oq=when%20runtim&sugexp=chrome,mod=0&sourceid=chrome&client=ubuntu&channel=cs&ie=UTF-8&q=when%20runtime%20exec%20doesn%27t&qscrl=1) for information about common `Runtime.exec()` traps (most of the information applies equally to the newer `ProcessBuilder` API as well)

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the answer to my question. I still seem to be having some problem as it's not unzipping, but I think that's a different question.

Comment: @user1068470: chances are the problem you have now is mentioned (and explained) in the article I mention above. Read it, it's well worth it.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the `find` argument to the desired directory `find /Users/abc -name '*.zip' -exec unzip {} \`

or as suggested by Joachim Sauer switch to the `ProcessBuilder` class.

Comment: I think `cd`is a built-in command and can not be used as a program.

Comment: Yes you're right the shell is not invoked. He can still invoke a shell and use the `-c` option to pass a command to be executed, like `bash -c 'cd /dir; find ...'` but that's not a very good solution ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Why not replace the starting directory "." in the find command?:

```
public void unzip(String workingDrirectory) {
  try {
    Runtime unzipProcess = Runtime.getRuntime();
    unzipProcess.exec("find " + workingDrirectory + " -name '*.zip' -exec unzip {} \\");
  } catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Within command you can provide `[-d exdir]` argument and `exdir` will have unzipped files.